# New to Programming and Getting an error

Tags: eclipse, launch

I am new to programming. To be very honest today is my first day and i am trying to learn Java by watching some YouTube videos.
I put this code in eClipse and

```
public class HelloWorld1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.printIn("Hello World");
   }
 }
```

I am getting the message 'Unable to Launch' The selection can't be launched and there are no recent launches' 
Please advise. Thanks

Comment: You should also find some tutorials/videos on how to set up eclipse. I'm not sure anyone can help you with that sparse information ...

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped PrintLn. (You wrote PrintIn).

Comment: Thanks! I thought that i will get an email when somebody will answer. Today i was answering someone's problem and i saw your answer. Thanks